# Firefox 11.0 Right-Click Dropdown Menu (and Menu Options at Window Top) Flickering - Potential Bug?

Tags: firefox, right-click

About a week ago my Windows 7 machine starting exhibiting odd Firefox behavior.  When I right click on something the drop-down menu flickers and when the mouse is hovering over a field, I can't really see it.

This same behavior happens in other ways too, like in the top File, Edit , View, etc menus.  I click them and they flicker, when I hover over them, and then they get obscured when I hover over the one I want.

I did some research and didn't really find anything.  Some people found similar behavior in applications THEY were building.  But mine is a global problem.  Happens on all sites, as far as I can tell.  This is why I suspect it's my Firefox installation.

I thought about reinstalling, but if there was another option, I'd like to explore that too.

The behavior is not really capture-able, so I don't have anything except words to describe it.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on. You can try searching the Firefox bug list at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ to see if your problem has been reported. If not, you can report it there. Firefox developers do pay attention to bugs reported, though not every bug will get immediate attention.

Comment: This might be the problem you have https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694904.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Firefox after an uninstall.  lorengphd's solution did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  To fix it I changed a setting:

(Press 'alt' to view top menu then)
Tools > Options > Advanced > General (tab).

Turn off "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer if it does indeed work for you!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.  I think it was a bug so the reinstall worked...  Thanks anyway, though.